# K8s cluster deployment error: nc: bad address 'xx'

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod, init, netcat

```
host@host:~$ kubectl logs kafka-0 -c init-zookeeper
nc: bad address 'zookeeper-0.zookeeper-headless-service.default.svc.cluster.local'
```

I have deployed an k8s cluster. When the application pod was installed, the pod keep in the Init state. I try to find out where goes wrong, only get this error below.

```
pml@pml:~/bfn-mon/k8s$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
broker-59f66ff494-lwtxq             0/1     Init:0/2   0          41m
coordinator-9998c64b8-ql7xz         0/1     Init:0/2   0          41m
kafka-0                             0/1     Init:0/1   0          41m
host@host:~$ kubectl logs kafka-0 -c init-zookeeper
nc: bad address 'zookeeper-0.zookeeper-headless-service.default.svc.cluster.local'
```

Would someone can tell what's going wrong? How can I fix it?

I would expect someone who did have the same problem, or know what's going wrong, and give some debug instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During Pod startup, the kubelet delays running init containers until the networking and storage are ready. Then the kubelet runs the Pod's [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) in the order they appear in the Pod's spec.

For pods stuck in an init state with a bad address, It means  the PVC may not be recycled correctly so the storage is not ready so the pod will be init state until it gets cleared.

From this [link](https://docs.microfocus.com/doc/Network_Operations_Management/2020.08/TSPodsStuckinInitState), you can follow below solutions:

1. Check if PVs are created and bound to all expected PVCs.
2. Run `/opt/kubernetes/bin/kube-restart.sh` to restart the cluster.